# Publish Web application to ZIP file from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I want to publish my Web application to a ZIP file.  To date I have been doing this by publishing to the file system, then manually zipping the output.

Is there a way of creating the ZIP file directly from Visual Studio?  I've tried publishing using the publish method "Web Deploy Package".  This generates a ZIP file, but the ZIP file contains a folder hierarchy that looks something like:

```
Content\C_C\...\MySolutionFolder\MyWebApp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
```

that mimics the folder hierarchy on my development machine.  I just want the actual web content, i.e. the content of the PackageTmp folder.

I don't understand why the ZIP file contains this folder hierarchy: it means that deployments created on two different development machines with different working folders for the same source-controlled Visual Studio solution will produce different packages.